# how to enable Last-Modified header for static resources served by Google App Engine (Java version)?

Tags: http, google-app-engine, last-modified

Is there a way to turn on the `Last-Modified` header for static resources served up by Google App Engine?  I have a large zip file that my app serves up to an iPhone client app, and I'd like to only download it if the `Last-Modified` date indicates that it is newer than the cached copy on the iPhone.

PS: I am using the Java version of Google App Engine.

**Solution:** I ended up writing a simple webapp to serve up my own static resources.  Not hard to do.  There is a small configuration step I had to do to get App Engine to serve static files, which is documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, App Engine doesn't currently appear to support conditional gets for static resources. You might want to file a bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) about that.