# File.lastModified() returns stale date on Google App Engine

Tags: java, http, google-app-engine, servlets

So [recently I learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218124/how-to-enable-last-modified-header-for-static-resources-served-by-google-app-engi) that in order to serve static files with a `Last-Modified` header from Google App Engine, I had to write my own (simple) servlet to do that.  OK fine, I went and did it, results can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/f1745c57a).

But now I find that `File.lastModified()` is always **returning the same value**, no matter that I have `touch`ed the file, even tried outright replacing it, and also re-deployed my app.  The headers always come back with the same Last-Modified field:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="java-intro.zip"
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Aug 2009 17:48:41 GMT
Last-Modified-in-millis: 1249408121000
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2009 20:47:59 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 0
```

Also curious is that it comes back with zero content-length, despite the fact that I am setting that in the `HttpServletResponse`, and I get back the proper data when I download it using my browser.

What gives, Google App Engine?

Comment: Have you posted this question on Google App Engine Group?

Comment: Yup: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/a539b26950d97dd4/72a5d257f83f1ea6?lnk=gst&q=last-modified#72a5d257f83f1ea6

Comment: Did you solve this eventually? From the top of my head, I would guess that if you upload updated files to GAE, their process of distributing your static files to their static-file-servers probably hashes the contents of the files to see if they need to be updated or something like that - without updating the lastModified on the files, which would be really bad. Whatever... did you solve it?

Comment: I never solved it. Sad to say it, but I gave up on App Engine after too many problems like this, and have gone back to hosting my own Tomcat instance for a more traditional servlet environment.